# How to set access rights for Project/task in openerp?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

In Openerp :

In project:module

How can only a task-owner/creator can delete the task & not other members of that group(Project/Manager)?? How to set access rights for this.

please explain

Answer (score 0):

[Security click here](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/04_security/)

and create a acess permission in a file called "**ir.model.access.csv**"

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_shipment,access_shipment,model_shipment,group_shipment_admin,1,1,1,1
```

and provide only read permission

and the other way is inherit the the delete method and put your and then return to super delete function

please let me if you have any   more doubts

Comment: hey thanks but where i will get  "ir.model.access.csv" file ??

Comment: Hi yashasvee,
you can find it over /addons/base/security of your openerp installation

you have to add it in your custom module